# How do I gracefully handle nil cases in collections throughout my entire app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I always get an error message like this:

```
undefined method 'firm_size' for nil:NilClass
```

When iterating over a collection and come upon some nil case.

I usually have to go into my view and add an `if` statement around this particular attribute to handle nil cases.

This seems like a very un-DRY approach.

Is there a more elegant way to handle these types of cases in Rails? Not just `nil` objects in a collection, but objects that may have an attribute that is `nil` - which is actually what is happening here.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

For more context on this particular instance of the error:

This is in my `Scores#index` view -

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= "First Client" %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Firm Size</td>
    <td><%= best_in_place client.score, :firm_size, :type => :input, :nil => "Add Score for Firm Size" %></td>
```

This is my `scores_controller.rb` the relevant parts:

```
class ScoresController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :load_clients

  def index
    @weight = current_user.weight
    @scores = current_user.scores

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @scores }
    end
  end

    private 

    def load_clients
        @clients = current_user.clients     
    end         

end
```

This is the server log:

```
Started GET "/scores" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-10 18:38:05 -0500
Processing by ScoresController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Weight Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "weights".* FROM "weights" WHERE "weights"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1
  Score Load (10.9ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."client_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Score Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."client_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Rendered scores/index.html.erb within layouts/application (276.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 283ms
```

This is the record in question (i.e. `client.score` when `client.id = 2`)

```
1.9.3p194 :089 > d = Client.find(2)
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Client id: 2, name: "Jack Daniels", email: "jack@abc.com", phone: 1234567890, firm_id: 2, created_at: "2012-09-05 19:26:07", updated_at: "2012-10-07 02:44:51", user_id: 1, last_contact: "2012-02-10", vote: false, vote_for_user: false, next_vote: "2012-07-12", weighted_score: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :090 > d.score
  Score Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."client_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

As I said before, this error is raised whenever a nil record (or attribute) is encountered. In this particular case, the nil record is for the `2nd` Client record that has been assigned no score.

Comment: Please show the context around how you're getting this error.

Comment: In cases where I'm looking for something "elegant" I sometimes try to write pseudo-code that I wished worked.  Could you imagine some code that would handle `nil` elegantly for your collections?

Comment: I just added more context - but I am not trying to solve just THIS particular problem, rather the more broad ranging case of encountering `nil` records or attributes of records and have it be handled gracefully.

Comment: @Larsenal That's an interesting approach, but I imagine this would be a case that all Rails developer's encounter - no? I can't be the only one whose iterators return nil objects or objects with nil attributes? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My point was simply this... if you can't imagine something more elegant than an `if` statement, your search for something more elegant is likely to be fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, assuming `best_in_place` is a helper, you could handle the nil in the helper.  Just pass in `client`, rather than the `client.score`.

The point is that *somewhere* you will have an if statement.  Just put it in the best spot.

Comment: `best_in_place` is a gem, and is not in all of my views. Just in some sections. 

Once I add an `if` statement to this view, I solve this particular problem - but it doesn't help me all throughout my app (say when I create a new resource and a new view where I am iterating through a diff collection - I will have to put in `if` statements all throughout my views).

That's the part I would rather not have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is consistently returning nil for something that shouldn't be nil, then perhaps it might be best to rethink how the functions are being called.  It is often nice to have a (or numerous) custom nil class(es) though. You could write extensions on `NilCLass` to catch the functions that you have, but this can be an issue if you get function names that are the same for different situations.  You could also potentially create a singleton in all your classes that helper methods point to if particular attributes are nil

Comment: It's not consistently returning nil for things that shouldn't. The issue is not the `nil` value being returned. That it is returning `nil` is the expected part - e.g. cycling through a collection where an attribute `client.score.firm_size` returns nil - but say `client.score.value` is legit. So the issue is handling the nil returned by that attribute gracefully. It's a common problem I find when iterating over collections of data to be displayed in a view.

Comment: I think the best option is to just add a boolean to see whether it's nil.  If you're worried about it cluttering your view, you could define a helper method that performs the operation.  Moving forward, it might be useful to populate the field with some meaningful data if null isn't what you want (a score of 0 or -1?)

Comment: How do I populate the field some meaningful data other than nil? In the migration?

Comment: Every time you create a new object make sure that you populate the field with a piece of data.  ex. `Client.create(score: 0)` assuming that you can mass assign the value.  Otherwise use `c = Client.new` then `c.score = 0` then `c.save`

Comment: If the you want to retroactively add data to fields that are nil, then yes, you can do that with a migration